# Getting Data from HubSpot REST api with Azure Data Factory - all contacts (Pagination)

Tags: pagination, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to get ALL contacts from Hubspot, but hubspot has a limit of 100 contacts per call, so I need to set up pagination in Data Factory to get all 25,000 contacts

This is the GET url I used to get a portion of the contacts `https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/lists/all/contacts/all?hapikey=[mykey]&vidOffset=1`

How do I set Data Factory up to retrieve all contacts?

Answer (score 0):

I think as per the doc https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/contacts/get_contacts 
they use the &vidOffset=X to navigate to the next page . I think we can use that value  for pagination . The below article may help.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I used vidOffset for Pagination and it just keeps looping because when it reaches the last page the vidOffset becomes 0 again instead of null. I don't know how to set it up so when 'has-more=false' the import stops.

Comment: We can use dynamic expression to check if vidOffset = 0 then set that to null , but i think we may have issues with the datatypes . Does the setting the 'has-more=false' worked for you ?

Comment: Hi, I don't know how to integrate 'has-more' into the pagination settings in Azure Data Factory.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar situation in Hubspot but mine was with companies and not in contacts. If you make a recursive function or put the function in a while loop while returning the vidOffset each time and use that value on the next function call, you should be good.

In your case (azure data factory), try adding an "Until" activity. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity

Hopefully this helps out!